# How to use JSHINT programmatically within Node.js?

Tags: node.js, npm, jshint

I was using npm [`jshint`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jshint) package in command line tool, but now I want to use it programmatically. [Documentation](http://jshint.com/docs/api/) refers to this example, but it doesn't say how to include or `require` that `JSHINT` function

```
var source = [
  'function goo() {}',
  'foo = 3;'
];
var options = {
  undef: true
};
var predef = {
  foo: false
};

JSHINT(source, options, predef);

console.log(JSHINT.data());
```

Documentation refers that

> JSHint exposes a JavaScript API for programmatic access in
>   environments like web browsers and Node.js.

But exposes **how**?

I installed the npm package *locally* (I want it locally)

```
npm install jshint --save
```

and I did as it's there and I get

```
JSHINT(code, JShintOpt);
^
ReferenceError: JSHINT is not defined
```

I also tried

```
const JSHINT = require('jshint');
```

But it doesn't work either.

Comment: You should install it as a dev dependency though ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the following:

```
const { JSHINT } = require('jshint');
```

Which is equivalent to:

```
const JSHINT = require('jshint').JSHINT;
```